# Android biometrics login

Tags: android

I have set up finger print login on an app, however this has caused a technical issue to arise. Traditionally the user would enter their username and password and click the login button which would verify their credentials against the record inside the database. If successful the database would return the users first name and userId which would be stored in a variable and used through the app.

Now, however when the user logs in with the finger print, there is no database transaction anymore so I don't get to pull back the user details. How are app makers working around this? When I log in with other apps using the finger print sensor the app still has to verify my account and interact with the database even without my username or password. Any thoughts on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution to this was to disable fingerprint login until the user logs in the traditional way the first time. Using a boolean to track if its a first login or not. During the first login the database transaction occurs and I simply store all the users details I need i shared preferences meaning further db transactions are not necessary.

When the user opens the app for the second time they can use the finger print login from now on.